# Google Play Store :Update rejected - Not adhering to Google Play Developer Programme Policies

Tags: google-play, android-security

My app was put down by google and the reason was they told was "Not adhering to Location permission policy" and my old permissions were as below. Here i have removed background location permission in my next update.

```
android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, 
android.permission.CALL_PHONE, 
android.permission.CAMERA, 
android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, 
android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES, 
android.permission.INTERNET, 
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, 
android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES, 
android.permission.VIBRATE, 
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE, 
com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE
```

After that I have updated my permission and tried creating update/release of the app but this time they rejected the update with the reason "Not adhering to Google Play Developer Programme Policies". My latest permission are as below.

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, 
android.permission.CALL_PHONE, 
android.permission.CAMERA, 
android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, 
android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES, 
android.permission.INTERNET, 
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, 
android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES, 
android.permission.VIBRATE, 
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE, 
com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE
```

I am unable to rectify the exact issue so as to resolve it. Kindly help.